# UITypeEditor in PropertyGrid with multiselection

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I have a custom object that can be edited from a PropertyGrid (DevExpress) via a custom TypeEditor (talking about .NET, c# and winforms).

The "entry point" in my custom UITypeEditor is the method

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
                                 IServiceProvider provider,
                                 object value)
```

that is called when someone tries to edit the value from the propertyGrid.

Everything works fine, but how can I handle a multiselection? When someone selects two objects in the property grid, value param is null, Is there any way to get a list with the values? Or any way to handle this type of behaviour?

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, context.Instance contains an array of objects with the selected values:

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
    object[] selectedValues = (object[])context.Instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as arrive at office on Monday!!